# When did Ari Spyros start working for Axelrod?

Tags: plot-explanation, billions

I've totally missed the part in *Billions* when Spyros started working for Axelrod. Was that ever shown? if yes, when did it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ari was hired (off-screen) and introduced as the Head of Compliance of Axe Capital at the start of Season 3 (Episode 1) in the episode entitled *Tie Goes To The Runner*.

Episode Recap - [**Here**](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2018/03/194280/billions-recap-season-3-episode-1-summary)